# Getting the cursor position of a GtkEntry

Tags: gtk

Slightly odd that there's not a get_entry_cursor_position() method, so my code is

```
GtkEntry * entry = ...;
GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_object_get_property( G_OBJECT(entry), "cursor-position", &value );
```

but the return value is undefined. So how do I find out where the cursor is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the magic is via

```
gtk_editable_get_position( GTK_EDITABLE(entry) );
```

which is not immediately apparent from the object hierarchy!